# How to Upgrade 16.04 Linux Kernel to 4.5?

Tags: kernel, 16.04

I need some features in the Linux Kernel 4.5. It would be great if there is coming any support for it soon. I am interested in how you can upgrade 16.04 to Linux kernel 4.5?

---

How to Upgrade 16.04 Ubuntu's kernel to 4.5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install any kernel to any version of Ubuntu from [Mainline Kernel PPA](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/)

The 4.5 kernel will not be included in Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: How is the support? What will break?

Comment: There is no support from canonical. But it is very unlikely that anything will "break".

Comment: worst thing that could happen is a kernel panic, but, but as long you not remove the older kernel you always can go back and uninstall the newer kernel.

Comment: What does that mean, 4.5. will not be included in rep. I hope we will get an update to 4.5 or 4.6 with 16.04.1 (when ever it will be released).

Answer (score 1):

As of the time of writing this (December 2016) you can simply install the package `linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04-edge` to get kernel 4.8.

According to the package description, this will always keep your Ubuntu 16.04 machine up to date with "the latest generic kernel image available".